# Ho to make current menu active on query page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Ok I use this script to change my menu style to highlight current page. I place this script in in my header page and php `require_once` the header page on other pages.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
  $('a').each(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('href') == window.location.href) {
      $(this).addClass('current');
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

I set .current class in my styles.css.

So everything works fine to highlight current page menu.

The only problem is this script doesn't work whenever I hit query like sorting or filtering database in the current page. I think it happens because the changes of dynamic address like `/page.php` to `/page.php?hjggj=hbhj` etc...

I need solution to this. Note that I will not use html and css assign class to current page method.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to:

```
if ($(this).prop('href') == window.location.href.replace(/\?.*/,"")) {
      $(this).addClass('current');
}
```

Full Code:

```
$(function(){
  $('a').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('href') == window.location.href.replace(/\?.*/,"")) {
        $(this).addClass('current');
    }
  });
});
```

I think you were comparing:

```
"/page.php" == "/page.php?ewrfwefwef"
```

which returns `false`. So what I'm doing is stripping every query string.

Comment: Thank you but this causes code error. Or I missed something?

Comment: @user3500464, yes I had missed a `)`. Now check it out

Comment: Thank you again. But again your code produces error.

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work, plus, no current page highlight this time.

Comment: @user3500464, can you show me what is the `href` of your `a` looks like?

Comment: do you mean like index.php? That's all. On the page with query, like admin.php I have dynamic table in that page, so when I sort the table the address will change from admin.php to admin.php?dwzTableOrder=yes&dwzTableOrderField=activeStat;DESC in this case.

Answer (score 0):

While targetting a unordered list menu:
Initiate it in document-ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href="'+window.location.pathname.split('/').pop()+'"]').parent('li').addClass('current');
});
```

Sample menu where it works:

```
<ul class="nav">
<li><a href="index.php">Index</a></li>
<li><a href="service.php">Service</a></li>
<li><a href="portfolio.php">Portfolio</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm sure I have proper menu exactly as you show but the code does not work in my page. Perhaps because I require_once the header things getting complicated in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#nav a').each(function(index) {
$navA = this.href.split('/')[4].split('?')[0];
$winA = String(window.location).split('/')[4].split('?')[0];
if($navA == $winA){
    $(this).addClass('current');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code :

```
function parseUrl( url ) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = url;
    a.search = '';
    return a;
}
var currentLocation=parseUrl(window.location.href);
$(function(){
    $('a').each(function() {
        if (this.href == currentLocation.href) {
            $(this).addClass('current');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you share your actual html? Is there displaying any error using my code?